# Laravel: why a registered service provider is not called when instantiating its provided class?

Tags: php, laravel, dependency-injection

This is my service provider:

```
<?php

namespace App\Providers;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Config;
use Illuminate\Support\ServiceProvider;

class ESServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    /**
     * Bootstrap the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function boot()
    {
        //
    }

    /**
     * Register the application services.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->singleton('\Elastica\Search', function ($app) {
            $client = new \Elastica\Client(array(
                'host' => env('ES_HOST'),
                'port' => env('ES_PORT')));
            $search = new \Elastica\Search($client);
            $search->addIndex(Config::get('constants.es_index'))->addType(Config::get('constants.es_type'));
            return $search;
        });
    }
}
```

When injecting instances of `\Elastica\Search\` the closure (2nd param to `singleton()`) doesn't get called (verified using `var_dump()` / `dd()`).  The provider is registered correctly - verified as above. Why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason, in Laravel 5.4 and above, is that the first param to `singleton()` (and similar binding functions) must not have a leading slash. So, changing it to `'Elastica\Search'` fixes the problem. It took me about an hour of debugging to realize this - hopefully this post saves someone this time...

Laravel website post explaining this change: http://laravel-guide.readthedocs.io/en/latest/upgrade/ - search for `Binding Classes With Leading Slashes`.